# How do I post my Javascript to a page?

Tags: c#, html, ajax, json

This website...

```
http://doctorjs.org/
```

Says I have to post my javascript to:

```
http://doctorjs.org/analyze
```

How on Earth do I do that?

Comment: Not sure if spam. Otherwise, click the "try it out" button.

Comment: doesn't look like spam. Their repo is on GitHub https://github.com/pcwalton/doctorjs and Mozilla labs refers to it as well https://mozillalabs.com/category/doctor-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pete,

It looks like that page expects a post request. therefore, you have to read the instructions on the page (http://doctorjs.org/) :). it says in the page to post it to here:

direct quote:

***Just POST to http://doctorjs.org/analyze with the src field set to your source
code, and the doctor will give you an analysis in JSON. [Try it out](http://doctorjs.org/try.html)!***

http://doctorjs.org/try.html

lol - give it a 'proper' try on the try.html page. good luck